# Remove <li> element from <ul> onclick without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment i need to remove an li element created by jQuery when it has been clicked.

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#likeform").submit(function(event) {
      var input = $(this).children("input[name='thing']")
      var thing = $(input).val()
      $("#likes").append("<li>" + thing + "</li>")
      $(input).val("")
      event.preventDefault()
    })
  })
  var li = $('<li/>')
    .onclick(function() {
      $(this).remove()
    })
}())

var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
for (var i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
  listitems[i].onclick = this.parentNode.removeChild((this))

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>My New Pen!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/index.processed.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>What do you like?</h1>
  <form id=likeform>
    <input name=thing placeholder="a thing you like" size=30>
    <input type=submit>
  </form>

  <ul id=likes></ul>
  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Currently this has been successful apart from i need to manually reload the page for the change to take effect

Comment: Is this what you are saying?
1. load page
1. click 
1. observe bad behavior
1. reload page
1. everything looks fine

Comment: yes, i load the page and add an element, click that element, refresh and it removes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
var li = $('<li/>').onclick(function() {
    $(this).remove()
});
```

First of all you don't need the comparison operators (`<`, `>`) as JQuery will select elements by their tag names. Also, you can't add event listeners the "normal" way on dynamically created elements.

This is discussed right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1359018/how-do-i-attach-events-to-dynamic-html-elements-with-jquery).

To fix your problem replace the above with this:

```
$(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Working example:

```js
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#likeform").submit(function(event) {
      var input = $(this).children("input[name='thing']")
      var thing = $(input).val()
      $("#likes").append("<li>" + thing + "</li>")
      $(input).val("")
      event.preventDefault()
    })
  })
  var li = $(document).on("click", "li", function() {
    $(this).remove();
  });
}())

var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
for (var i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
  listitems[i].onclick = this.parentNode.removeChild((this))

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>What do you like?</h1>
<form id=likeform>
  <input name=thing placeholder="a thing you like" size=30>
  <input type=submit>
</form>

<ul id=likes></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is essentially what you are trying to do:

```js
$('li').each(function (i) {
  $(this).click(() => $(this).remove());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

would you please try following.

```
(function() {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#likeform").submit(function(event) {
      var input = $(this).children("input[name='thing']")
      var thing = $(input).val()
      $("#likes").append("<li>" + thing + "</li>")
      $(input).val("")
      event.preventDefault()
    })
  })
}())

var listitems = document.getElementsByTagName("li")
for (var i = 0; i < listitems.length; i++) {
  listitems[i].onclick = this.parentNode.removeChild((this))

}
$(document).on("click", "#likes li", function(){
 $(this).remove();
});
```